# How to add more disk space to the local drive?

Tags: windows-8, disk-management

I am using Windows 8 Single Language 64 bit. I have > 350 GB Unallocated space in my hard disk. I want to add this > 350 GB unallocated space to C: drive where Windows is installed. I have checked using 'Extend Volume...' in 'Disk Management', which is currently disabled. Is there some simple way to do this? Kindly don't answer like backup your data and format your hard disk/drive, use third party software, etc. Kindly help me and ask for any further clarifications if needed.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid 3rd-party software?? Partition Magic, Acronis tools (etc) could help you solve it in short time.

Comment: What's your current partition structure look like?  Specifically, is your C:\ a primary partition or a logical drive?

Comment: Can you provide a screen-shot of your Disk Management screen? Also show us what you mean by "Extend volume is disabled"

Comment: Step 1:  Make a complete backup.

Comment: @DanielRHicks : Thanks, but as said earlier, I don't want that option. Because, when it is possible to 'Extend Volume...' without backup for other drives, then why not C: drive where Windows is installed?

Comment: @Jet : I am very much concerned about the data being sent from my computer to these companies. Also, when it is possible to 'Extend Volume...' of other drives then why not C: drive where Windows is installed? If there is some configuration to be done, or some tricks then I can do it, otherwise, 3rd-party software is the last option.

Comment: @ernie : Primary partition. Reference : https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-HehCULUfL6YnJzQjFYa0puN00&usp=sharing

Comment: @MonkeyZeus : https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-HehCULUfL6YnJzQjFYa0puN00&usp=sharing

Comment: I'm just saying that step 1, of whatever process you use, should be to make a complete backup.  Many folks have come here with sorry stories of how they did "simple" reconfigs without doing a backup first, and are wondering how to recover.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshots. This issue may simply be occurring because the unallocated space is to the right of the E: drive. I see that you are only using 67 of 460 GB on your E: drive. Can you move the 67GB to your C: drive, Delete Volume of E: drive, which should give you 795.26 unallocated space, extend your C: drive to desired size, create New Simple Volume with remaining unallocated space, then move the 67GB back to the new partition? If you have a USB hard drive laying around I 100% recommend backing up your important stuff to it before performing this.

Comment: @user2744197 How is this issue coming along, any luck yet?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus : Thanks, this was the right answer and I have followed this step after trying one software which was of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I transferred my files back to C: drive, deleted E: drive, extended C: drive and created E: drive again (with the space remaining). This is because a partition can only be extended if there is space next to it (contiguous).

Comment: Would you please modify this to say "partition" instead of "drive", for clarity?  This is especially important in the last sentence. Thanks. Also, I think you didn't understand that you could use the Easus software to just -move- E: up so that the free space was adjacent to C:. Sorry if I did not explain that well enough to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

If your unformatted space is next to the formatted space the partition can usually be expanded to encompass it.
If you can't do what you need to do in the Disk Management Console you can try using the command line.
[This page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771473.aspx) explains it, but the gist is to:
Open command line, may need to run as administrator.
type diskpart and hit enter.
type list volume and hit enter.
type select volume 
volumenumber here is the existing partition that you want to expand.
now type extend and hit enter.
if you specify a size it will expand that much, but if you leave the size parameter out it will fill the empty space.

Comment: Thanks Kemo, but command line is the same as Disk Management Console. Its hard to use cmd every time so Microsoft created Disk Management Console, which also helps them in revenues by saying they have a beautiful interface. And this is the link to screenshots which would help https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-HehCULUfL6YnJzQjFYa0puN00&usp=sharing

Comment: I have had success accomplishing tasks in command line that are allowed when using the gui.
While the Disk Management Console does use the same commands, it can disallow them for unexplained reasons even when able to be successfully executed.
I definitely agree it's cumbersome to use regularly, but I didn't realize you needed to run it often, I thought it was just one time.

Comment: Even one time was enough.

Comment: I am glad you were able to get it fixed.
My suggestion would only work if the free space was contiguous anyway, which I saw later it was not.

Answer (score 0):

If your Unallocated space is the is contiguous with your C partition, meaning that it is the part of the same disk and that you don't have any other partition except C. If this is the case than you can use **Extend volume**, via Disk Management.

Right click on C partition and select the **Extend volume** and click on **Next**. Select the all available space. Click on **Next** then **Finish**

Comment: Thanks Nikola. Its not contiguous. Reference: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-HehCULUfL6YnJzQjFYa0puN00&usp=sharing

Comment: :(  I think that you will have to rely on some third party software in your case

Comment: So sad that Microsoft still don't learn from its mistakes. On the other hand other companies have hundred mouths to feed because of Microsoft's 'mistakes'.

Comment: hehehe :)  Yep, fully agree with you!

Comment: I had to make changes to get the above situation. Because this problem could only be solved when I arrive on the above situation. MonkeyZeus suggested answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

So, you've got two issues:

The first is that you're trying to extend your boot partition, and as stated on [this Microsoft page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771473.aspx) (emphasis added):

> For logical drives, boot, or system volumes, you can extend the volume
>   **only into contiguous space** and only if the disk can be upgraded to a
>   dynamic disk.

Note that contiguous space means that the free space must be directly adjacent to the partition you want to grow.

If this was not your boot partition, you would first need to convert to a dynamic disk (as opposed to basic):

> For other volumes, you can extend the volume into noncontiguous space,
>   but you will be prompted to convert the disk to dynamic.

While you stated you didn't want to use third-party tools or backup to another disk (which is good practice to do anyway before futzing with partitions), I don't think you have any other options.

Comment: Got it. So sad that Microsoft still don't learn from its mistakes. On the other hand other companies have hundred mouths to feed because of Microsoft's 'mistakes'. Ya, and my Google Drive is updated (one more screenshot is added).

Comment: Thats right, I made changes to the arrive at the situation. After coming to this situation, I solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you really mean that you don't want to use 3rd party software, or you just don't want to spend money on it.  In any case, you need software that can move the partition that is between your "C:" partition and the free space. The free space for expanding a partition must be adjacent in virtually any scenario.

So if you don't mind -free- 3rd party software, Easus partition manager is great.  It's reliable, really free, and can help you move the intervening partition, say, to the end of the disk, so the free space will be adjacent to C: and then you can expand it.  The other reason I'd recommend Easus is that it has a very simple-to-use GUI;  most of the other free options are far less user-friendly.

Comment: Reasons not to use 3rd party softwares are mentioned above. Its not about money as the softwares also come in free version and there are also freeware software. Anyways, trying EaseUs now. Will notify about the results.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure I understand what you said about the 3rd party software, above.  But re. the backup issue, it's always a good idea to make a backup before modifying partitions, whehter C: or just a pure data drive, no matter what tool you use. And I hope I was clear that if you move the intervening partition, so that the free space is adjacent to C:, then you should be able to use "Extend Volume" as you wanted.

Comment: EaseUs also didn't solve the problem. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-HehCULUfL6YnJzQjFYa0puN00&usp=sharing shows the screenshots which will help in understanding the problem. MonkeyZeus suggested solution to the problem which I followed and solved it.

Comment: Please post the steps you followed, though I see there is a message, shown in the images, that wasn't included in the original question. I don't offhand see what solution you say helped you figure it out. Also in the future, please include any specific messages that you encounter that affect doing what you are trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: Posted. I added the screenshots as the question was not clear to many and they have asked it in comments about more information. There is also one screenshot to tell others about the steps they suggested and I followed but couldn't achieve my goal. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. You'll learn to improve your questions as you go along.  Just keep in mind that there are others who may look at it for a long time to come, so keep the information as complete as possible.