# how to merge unallocated space to drive c?

Tags: windows, partitioning

I am trying to merge unallocated space to drive c but unfortunately not able to do so. 
The drive c option is not showing extend option.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the disk manager which displays your partition information

Comment: There was a similar issue here: http://superuser.com/questions/657167/how-to-add-more-disk-space-to-the-local-drive#comment829413_657167

Comment: `The drive c option is not showing extend option.`   That’s because Windows will not let you mess around with the system drive. You will need a third-party partition-management program to do that.

Comment: @Synetech: At least since Windows Vista, the Disk Manager utility can and will extend or shrink the system/boot partition. No doubt the option is not appearing for the Question Asker because there is not in fact contiguous unallocated space at the end of the C drive.

Comment: Hmm, I could have sworn it doesn’t, but I don’t have a drive on hand with free space to check. It could also be a dynamic drive which I believe Windows can’t/won’t extend.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the system partition because (as @Synetech commented) Windows locks the C: partition  while you're booted into it.

In order to work with the partition you would need to either:

1. Boot into another OS if you have one installed on a different partition, **or**
2. Use a third party bootable tool. I used [EaseUS Partition Master Free Edition](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm), and it worked quite nicely.

A word of caution, if you do a lot of moving around, it's possible you may corrupt or otherwise break the MBR. Fixing this requires booting into a command prompt and executing `bootrec /fixmbr` or `bootrec /rebuildbcd`. A simple extension of the C: partition should not cause this, though.